# Using await Task.Delay() with Cancellation token to time out a method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, cancellation

I am looking at a method that is structured like the code below. What is the effect of the cancellation token? Is it so that if the calculation takes longer than 1 second it won't return a T and it throws an error?

```
public async Task<T> doSomething(CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken)) {
    await Task.Delay(1000, ct);

    //do something to calculate someT that might take a while

    return someT;
}
```

Comment: CancellationToken is for cancellation - the task from Task.Delay will be cancelled, throws an TaskCanceledException and taht will cancel the complete task

Comment: Task.Delay is documented - how to use and what it does

Comment: @SirRufo so is this kinda the same as a 1 second timeout in NUnit testing?

Comment: No, it is like a Thread.Sleep here (because you are awaiting it) but it is cancelable by the token

Comment: I am understanding you correctly that along the way while I am calculating someT and there are say two possible "paths" based on other states, I could use ct to cancel the delay on one path and let it go to completion but let the other path time out?

Comment: No, there is nothing like a timeout here. It will **delay** the execution for 1 second and then continue if not canceled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cancellation token as the name suggests is something that allows the asynchronous/parallel code to be cancelled. Consider the scenario of a user cancelling a long running process.

In your code, the `dosomething` method accepts a `CancellationToken` which it can use to determine whether or not to cancel execution early. There are various ways to do that. First you can call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on the `ct` variable which as the name suggests will throw an exception you can handle in the calling code if the operation is cancelled. You can also check `if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)` in a loop to see if it has been and then exit out of your method.

By passing it on to `Task.Delay(1000, ct);` you are giving `Task.Delay` a means of telling whether or not to continue waiting should a cancellation be requested before the time out has been reached.

I may be mistaken but it also seems you aren't sure as to the purpose of `Task.Delay()`; it is a means to stop execution on that line for a second before proceeding. The token gives it a way to exit early should the operation be cancelled as I mentioned earlier.